# Deploy Bot from Bot framework composer to azure function app

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I want to Deploy my Bot from Bot framework Composer to azure function app (node.js, ~12) and azure channel registration for testing and deploying to other channels.

[image]

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Comment: Yes, I finally got it working by removing the excess luis configs (keeping only Luis Authoring endpoint, key & location), then finally changing the Azure function platform to x64 Bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deploy your bot via Bot framework Composer, you should config your `Publish Configuration` in your publish profile. Please follow [this official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot) to get the publish config and paste it into your publish profile.

I tested the whole process on my side, it works perfectly for me:
[image]

Paste this to publish profile to deploy:
[image]

[image]

Test my echo bot:
[image]

Btw, while I test the whole process, I got a function runtime error after deployment
:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.BotFramework.Composer.Functions
```

When I change Azure function platform from 32 to 64, this issue got solved:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar trouble.
I did follow Microsft standard deployment procedure by running the following script:

node provisionComposer.js --subscriptionId= --name= --appPassword= --environment=

But, no luck. the script failed and returned the following error:

> using tenant id : 
> creating app registration
> user was not found
> ** provision failed **

I did make sure that I put in the right "subscription id".
Can any she some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: To solve this error run `az account show` on your azure cli, copy the tenantId. Open provisionComposer.js look for this line of code and insert your tenant Id.
`var tenantId = argv.tenantId ? argv.tenantId : '< insert tenant Id>';`

Then run your script but do not pass the --tenantId argv again.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Yes, it works. Alternatively, one can also add a new input parameter to specify tenantId to the provisionComposer script.